# DataGridView Cell Editing and Updating DB (C#)

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

I have a function to edit a cell in my dgv. And that is the problem. I can only edit one cell.

Here is my code so far:

```
        private void datagridview1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
        Connection();
        sqlconnection.Open();

        this.datagridview1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = true;
        this.rowIndex1 = e.RowIndex;
        this.datagridview1.CurrentCell = this.datagridview1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1]; //1 = only quantity can be edited, 0 = only item can be edited

        sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE inventory_table SET item = @item, quantity = @quantity WHERE id= " + this.datagridview1.Rows[this.rowIndex1].Cells["id"].Value, sqlconnection);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item", this.datagridview1.Rows[this.rowIndex1].Cells["item1"].Value);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", this.datagridview1.Rows[this.rowIndex1].Cells["quantity1"].Value);
        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        sqlconnection.Close();
        }
```

What am I missing? And what could I do so that I can edit multiple dgv cells and have them get updated in the DB?

Comment: So when you are editing cells only the first cell gets saved to the database?  Using this event to call updates is not a good idea to begin with, but you may want to ensure your object is getting cleaned up by adding a 'using' statement for the connection object

Comment: You should take a look at this article. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/ Also, why didn't you use a parameter for the where predicate too?

Comment: Doesn't really matter. I simply want to know the answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the problem is due to using the wrong event.  You appear to want to execute an update when the user finishes editing a row.

But your code lives in an event that fires after any cell finishes editing.  I can't say for certain what event you want.  That is dependent on your specifications.

But I'll bet that the [RowValidated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowvalidated(v=vs.110).aspx) event will meet your needs.  If not, check out the [RowStateChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowstatechanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event.  (And try the sample code for that event.  It should help you to get a feel for when the event fires.)

Answer (score 0):

> you can't update or delete multiple rows in gridview using gridview
>   editing or deleting method,  i believe there are no default events in
>   gridview to update or delete multiple records.
>
> but you can achieve this by using another procedure:
>
> 1>you can take a button in gridview footer or outside the grid
>   view,after putting all updated value to the grid cell write code on
>   footer_button click to update all records in the gridview.
>    2>you can use jQuery/ajax control on grid to update grid record on textbox_leave event.

Some samples you can look for the solution

- [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/788208/Update-Multiple-Rows-of-GridView-using-JSON-in-ASP)
- [here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Bulk-Edit-Update-Multiple-Rows-in-ASPNet-GridView-using-CheckBoxes.aspx)
- [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa992036(v=vs.140).aspx)