# how to update database using DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Basically i have a datagridview which is filled by a query upon the loading of the page to display all the incomplete orders in my database table as below:[image]

I was wondering if it's possible to allow the user to edit them so they can mark the incomplete orders as completed, i was thinking through either just allowing the column to be editable, or maybe a set of checkboxes alongside each row which would mark them as completed.

here's my current code the page:

```
Public Class processorders
    Dim sql As New sqlcontrol

    Private Sub ammendorders_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        If sql.HasConnection = True Then
            sql.RunQuery("SELECT customers.customer_id, first_name, second_name, phone_number, date_ordered, order_total, collection_method FROM (Orders INNER JOIN Customers on orders.customer_id = customers.customer_id) WHERE order_status='In Progress'")
            If sql.sqldataset.Tables.Count > 0 Then
                dgvData.DataSource = sql.sqldataset.Tables(0)
            End If
        End If

    End Sub
    'above queries database to find all incomplete orders



    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
```

Comment: It seems like the order status should be a drop down.  The DGV doesnt update the DB, it just shows the data to the user and collects input.  Your DB provider objects like the adapter does the updates.  In order to update you may need the Id column in the dataset, but the user need not see it, and if you do show it, make sure it is a ReadOnly column

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to edit the order_status field, you could set the the column as a DataGridViewComboBox which would contain all possible status values. Then create an event handler to update the database when the combo box value is changed.

Edit: Code

```
Private Sub MyDataGridView_RowValidated(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles MyDataGridView.RowValidated

  'update the data source here, could vary depending on the method used.
  if sql.HasConnection
    Dim sqlCmd as SqlCommand = new SqlCommand

    sqlCmd.connection = "<Your connection string>"
    sqlCmd.commandText = 
      String.format(
        "UPDATE Orders SET order_status='{0}' WHERE customer_id='{2}';",
        MyDataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(<order_status column index>).Value,
        MyDataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(<customer_id column index>).Value
      )
    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery
  end if
End Sub
```

Edit 1: Found another possible answer: [DataGridView Cell Editing and Updating DB (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29240269/datagridview-cell-editing-and-updating-db-c)

Edit 2: Changed sql.RunQuery to a SqlCommand object.

Comment: Can you provide some example code to help illustrate your answer?

Comment: How do i do this though? As the columns don't exist until the page is loaded, i don't see any way to change the column properties unless i'm missing something?

Comment: Glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it. This is hooked to a dropdown list but it can be hooked to any control in the grid:

```
' This enables you to capture the Update event on a gridview

Dim clickedRow As GridViewRow = TryCast(DirectCast(sender, DropDownList).NamingContainer, GridViewRow)


Dim cust_id As Label = DirectCast(clickedRow.FindControl("lbl_grd_id"), Label)
Dim status As DropDownList = DirectCast(clickedRow.FindControl("ddl_grd_crew_id"), DropDownList)


Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [your_orders_table] set status = @status where customer_id = @cust_id "

cmd.Parameters.Add("@cust_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(cust_id.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@status", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = status.Text

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.Connection = Me.sqlConnection1
Me.sqlConnection1.Open()
'execute insert statement
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Me.sqlConnection1.Close()
're-populate grid with a method call. if you don't the edits will not be reflected when the grid reloads 
fill_order_status_grd()

fill_order_status_grd.databind()
```

Comment: Converted this to VB. I just noticed your original code was VB not C#.